# Window Outlook 2016 'from address' not replying from the same address the message was sent to

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2016

Gmail accounts let you configure the ability to send email from a different address then the account. Let's say I have `me@company.com` setup as my email account and I want to send email from `support@company.com`.

In Gmail's `Settings > Account > Send mail as:` there is an option to set `Reply from the same address the message was sent to`. How can I get Windows Outlook 2016 to have this same behavior?

When setting up Outlook 2016 on Windows, I can add the alias such as `support@company.com` and send email from this address, but when I get email to this address and reply, the from address is being set to the default account address such as `me@company.com`

Comment: Is your Outlook connecting to a Gmail account?

Comment: @music2myear yes

Comment: Could you please check this and see if this addresses your question? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/reply-from-a-different-address/966f48fe-f147-4ff2-83bb-d1bdf2b915f4. The product is, however, 2010. I believe you can use a similar Macro.